# Can we do two Teams app target to same backend static web?

Tags: teams-toolkit

Need to do few teams apps target to same backend static web. How can do that in a correct way?

I tried target same TAB_ENDPOINT,TAB_DOMAIN,TAB_AZURE_STORAGE_RESOURCE_ID with few apps in deferent tenants. Want to know how can use same backend static web for few teams app in deferent tenants?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [Teams app manifest schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#sample-app-manifest).

If you want your apps target to same static web, you can update the `staticTab.contentUrl`, `staticTab.websiteUrl` and `configurableTabs.configurationUrl`, depends on which tab capability you are using.

If you want your teams apps target to same bot service, you can update the `bots.botId` or `composeExtensions.botId`.

If your app is created by Teams Toolkit, you can find your manifests in `appPackage/build/manifest.{envName}.json`.
Also, you can modify the `TAB_ENDPOINT` or `BOT_ID` in `env/.env.{envName}` and re-zip the Teams App package by click the command **Zip Teams App Package**.
[image]